# Query not in - to show "all other" except particular values

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi I have two tables one is tab_data and another one is tbl_catg

[image]

I want a result like in the image.  What is available in tbl_Catg should show as it is.  What is not available should show as "All Other"

The below query is showing the wrong result.

```
select 
   Future_Product_Category,
   sum(TYDOLLAR) ty 
from [dbo].[tbl_DATA] a
inner join [tbl_CATG] b on 
ISNULL(a.Future_Division,'NULLDIV')=ISNULL(b.Division,'NULLDIV') 
and IS NULL(a.Future_Product_Category,'NULLCATG')=ISNULL(b.CatgName,'NULLCATG')
group by Future_Product_Category

union All

select 
   'All Other', 
   A.TYDOllar 
from
   (select  
       Future_Division, 
       Future_Product_Category,
       sum(TYDOLLAR) TYDOllar
    from [dbo].[tbl_DATA] 
    group by Future_Division, Future_Product_Category) a 
   ,[tbl_CATG] b 
where 
    a.Future_Division=b.Division 
    and (a.Future_Product_Category not in (select  CatgName from [tbl_CATG] where a.Future_Division=b.Division ))
order by a.Future_Product_Category
```

Comment: Just some advice, [start using explicit joins (it's been a couple of decades)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). You used them in the first query and not the second...

Comment: The problem seems to be in the where clause in the bottom. `(select  CatgName from [tbl_CATG] where a.Future_Division=b.Division ))` Here, you are referencing the table alias a and b but outside of the scope of the sub query. That is, you haven't aliased `[tbl_CATG]` in this query so i'm unsure of what you are trying to do